# canvas-sketch error: "THREE.ParametricGeometry has been moved to /examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using canvas-sketch to create some Three.js content.

I used following command for Three.js template

```
canvas-sketch --new --template=three --open
```

The installed version is 1.11.14

```
canvas-sketch -v
```

When I try to access THREE.ParametricGeometry, it gives the error "THREE.ParametricGeometry has been moved to /examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js"

```
// Ensure ThreeJS is in global scope for the 'examples/'
global.THREE = require("three");
// Include any additional ThreeJS examples below
require("three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls");

const canvasSketch = require("canvas-sketch");

// code 
const geometry = new THREE.ParametricGeometry(calculateHelicoid, 25, 25)
// rest of the code
```

In order to fix it, I add the following require

```
require("three/examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js")
```

But then it gives the error:
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' line 6
threejs_marbles/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js

Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the wrong path, my require had examples/jsm/..., it should've been examples/js/...

```
require("three/examples/js/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js")
```